# Background Image in Jquery mobile

Tags: android, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am creating a web abb for android phones. I have an image which should be the background for all the pages. I have to use Slide transition for all the pages. If I add Background url option in CSS, it is not covering the whole screen. Is there any way that we can fit the image completely to all the screen resolutions.

Please help me guys.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this when you set you img background. Tell me if it works.

```
background-size:100% 100%;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to go with css background.

Still, there are other solutions, but they are not going to work (or work well) on older mobile devices. Reason, every jquery solutions are using position:fixed and that can cause problems on older android devices.

In case you are still willing to try take a look at this:

[jQuery plugin 1](http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/)

[jQuery plugin 2](https://github.com/weightshift/The-Personal-Page)

Answer (score 0):

In the css set the background size like this...

```
background-size: cover;
```

It will automatically fit the screen.

Comment: That will always happen, no matter how you do this, unless you use a larger image.